# when you are "a=b=c=ListNode(0,head)", does it take up more memory because of those a,b,c's?

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

when you are "a=b=c=ListNode(0,head)", does it take up more memory because of those a,b,c's?
What I mean to ask is, whether abc's are some pointers or duplicates of head starting from zeroth position.

Comment: Python assignments never make copies, everything is just references. So all the variables are references to the same `ListNode` instance.

Comment: `a = b = c = ListNode(0,head)` assigns *the same object* to three different variables. i.e. there is *only one `ListNode` created

Answer (score 0):

You asked two different questions.  Each of the names `a`, `b`, and `c` will be bound to the same object, in your case a `ListNode`.  So there is no duplication of ListNode memory.  Each of the associations will take a bit of memory, 32 to less that 200 bytes, depending on the context.  But this is so trivial that you usually should not worry about it.